# Google Cloud Storage slow download speed under custom domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I noticed the following issue, using the public url I can download the file at full speed, under my subdomain the download is much below the normal. Why this happen?

```
$ aria2c -x 1 https://storage.googleapis.com/gcs.mydomain.com/path/to/public/file.ext

[snip]

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
e77479|OK  |   228MiB/s|/home/skhaz/file.ext

$ aria2c -x 1 https://gcs.mydomain.com/path/to/public/file.ext

[snip]

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
cfcb2e|OK  |    17MiB/s|/home/skhaz/file.1.ext

$ du -h *.ext
62M file.1.ext
62M file.ext
```

Comment: The first one shows a download of over 1.8 Gbit/sec. Where are you downloading from (home Internet, business Internet, Compute Engine VM)? What happens if you increase the number of host connections (-x 4)? What happens when you repeat each command several times (is local caching a factor)?

Comment: The results are basically the same, I tested on my home and on the GCE. I'll try to test on a fresh project.

Comment: Do you have same settings like Location and Storage class on your custom domain bucket?